# prevent jquery action on button inside click event

Tags: jquery

I have a div to which I have added jquery click event so when you click it it takes you to a url. Inside that same div i have a button to delete the entry. Unfortunately  with my .click event when i click on delete it does delete it but it also takes me to the url. How do I prevent the .click event from being fired if the click was made over the button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            if ($(this).data("href") !== "") {
                window.open($(this).data("href"));
            }
        });
     });
</script>


<div class="box gallery clickable-row" id="item" data-href="www.amazon.com">
<div class="box-head clearfix">
    <div class="left">ghjlhgoig</div>
    <div class="right">$10</div>
</div>
<div class="box-content">
    <img src="/images/missing.gif">
    <form action="http://local.wishlist.com/lists/view/5" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="19">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Just to be clear if i click on the delete button i want it to submit the form and not send me to the url.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L14e6cau/2/ in this example i want to click on the delete button and not be taken to amazon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click even is propagating up from the delete button. There are two ways to deal with this.

(1) Check if the event bubbled up from the delete button:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('input[name="delete"]')) {
        if ($(this).data("href") !== "") {
            window.open($(this).data("href"));
        }
    }
});
```

(2) Stop the event from propagating:

```
$('input[name="delete"]').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: #1 worked perfectly tytytytytyty Exactly what i had in my mind but could put it down in js :)

Comment: I tried #2 before you suggested it and it didnt work for whatever reason. Only difference is that i added an id and used that instead of the input name

Comment: @bia.migueis - Both methods appear to work in this [jsdiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsoe9h9m/).

Comment: hmm weird... i clicked on the link and the example didnt work. I closed the page and started this comment but clicked on the fiddle again just to make sure and this time it actually worked as intended. not sure why but my site its working with option #1 so thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It seems like you want to change your jQuery selector from .clickable-row to something that only applies to the button which opens the new window.

garryp is correct. You can also use the jQuery method event.preventDefault();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).data("href") !== "") {
                window.open($(this).data("href"));
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

See the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: that makes it so it takes me to the url instead of deleting the entry even though i clicked on the delete button

Comment: the div is for a lst of tiles. i would like the whole tile to be clickable but i also would like the edit/delete buttons inside the tile because of the looks. i dont want it to take me to the url when i click on one of those buttons because thats not what you would want if you want to delete the item lol

Answer (score 0):

Return false from the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            if ($(this).data("href") !== "") {
                window.open($(this).data("href"));
            }
            return false;
        });
     });
</script>
```

Alternatively change the input type to "button" rather than "submit" which will stop it posting the form.

OK I understand what you're asking now. I think your options are the following:

1) On the URL add a redirect back to the page the request came from.

2) Alternatively post using an AJAX call. See [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

3) Post to an iframe (probably the easiest option).

Comment: [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) might also be an alternative.

Comment: return false makes it so it takes me to the url instead of deleting the entry which is what i want to do if i click over the belete button. same goes for stoppropagation

Comment: i tried doing the ajax post but it still goes to the url from the .click

Comment: i know this is not a thing but any chance i could do something like $(".clickable-row -.delete-item").click(...) ? or maybe something like $(".clickable-row").click(function() { if $(".delete-item") return false;});

Comment: See this quick code sample I've set up (some errors from the OP)  http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/L14e6cau/1/

Comment: that would make it so when you click on the tile to see the url you instead delete the item altogether